# how to convert below string to list of map?

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary

how can i convert below string to list of map?

```
[
    {externalId=externalId_2, 
    externalIdDocId=abc, 
    partyRoleExternalIdType=type_extId
    }, 
    {externalId=externalId_3, 
    externalIdDocId=xyz, 
    partyRoleExternalIdType=type_extId2
    }
]
```

i have tried converting the string to list of strings

```
List<String> externalIdlist = (List<String>) gson.fromJson(cbExternalIds, List.class);
```

and then convert one by one each string to map

```
Map<String, String> externalIdMap = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(externalIdlist.get(i)), Map.class);
```

this works but is there a better solution?

Comment: Please go through this & edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @jens i have updated the question with what i have tried

Comment: you can do it in single step. Check my Ans, the one using Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet will do the needful. I am assuming that your expected output is of `List<Map<String, String>` type.

```
List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<>();
input = input.substring(2, input.length() -2);

String[] split = input.replace("}, {", "!").split("!");
for (String s : split) {
    String[] split1 = s.trim().split(",");
    Map<String, String> m1= new HashMap<>();
    for (String s1 : split1) {
        String[] kv = s1.trim().split("=");
        m1.put(kv[0],kv[1]);
    }
    output.add(m1);
}
return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HashMap<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString.replaceAll("=",":"), HashMap.class);
```

First you have to convert your string to a correct Json by replacing th "=" chars to ":" and the use the ObjectMapper to convert it into **HashMap Class** Object

**ObjectMapper** parse Json to a specific Class object

Comment: *Try this* is not an answer. Explain what you have done and why.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to parse it manually with string methods like this:

1. Remove the `[` and `]`with `replaceAll`
2. Split the remaining into Object tokens with `split(",")`
3. Remove each token `{` and `}`, then split its parameters like in step 2 with `split(",")`, then create params key-value pairs with splitting up with `split("=")`. From each pair you can get the value as the 2nd argument, or simply discard the key.
4. Now you have array with arrays of parameters, from which you can create manually the Objects

   `MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.setExternalId(tokens[0]);
    obj.setexternalIdDocId(tokens[1]);
    obj.setpartyRoleExternalIdType(tokens[2]);`
5. Finally manually create your Map or Array and add the created objects.

If you want to use GSon, Jackson or other, you have to create the Object model with the 3 parameters first, then call the parser with `MyObject[] myObjArray = gson.fromJson(myJson, MyObject[].class);`

Answer (score 0):

```
new Gson().fromJson(inputString, new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>().getClass())
```

**Tested** and got following **result** -

[image]

This will work for your use case.